# AdvancedDataGrid does not displays object properties

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

I have following data:

```
var data: ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
            [
                { name: "ProductA", user: {login: "loginA", email: "emailA"} },
                { name: "ProductB", user: {login: "loginB", email: "emailB"} },
                { name: "ProductC", user: {login: "loginC", email: "emailC"} }
            ]
        );
```

This array is a data provider for my AdvancedDataGrid:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{data}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Product" width="55" dataField="name" /> 
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="User" dataField="user.login" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Email" dataField="user.email" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

The problem is - AdvancedDataGrid does not displays properties of nested User object, but the simple DataGrid does.
What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a labelFunction or an itemRenderer. Here is an example of a labelFunction

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="User" labelFunction="getUserLogin" />
```

which calls

```
private function getUserLogin(item:Object, column:AdvancedDataGridColumn) {
  return item.user.login;
}
```

The item argument will be the data that your cell is receiving.

Comment: I should add that I don't really know what your object model looks like, so you should make your labelFunction, then put a breakpoint on the first statement and examine the "item" in the debugger so you can address the correct property you are looking for, wherever it is in the structure.

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid was patched to support complex paths but I don't think that AdvancedDataGrid was.  More details:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-9801

You can use a labelFunction instead.